# Git log issue in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I am trying to get the commit messages between 2 tags for a Powershell build script and I am hitting a road block. This is the command I an using,

```
$oldVersion = '0.0.1'
$version = '0.0.2'
git log $oldVersion..$version --pretty=format:'-%s %n'
```

Nothing back as a response. The tags exist because if I run:

```
git log 0.0.1..0.0.2 --pretty=format:'-- %s %n'
```

All of the commit messages come back. The command doesn't error, just returns nothing.

It has to be something really silly, I'm just not a wiz at powershell or git so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log $oldVersion`..$version --pretty=format:'-%s %n'
```

`.` needs escaping here.